# Add listener in the array when specific value equal then update SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to add listener in the array on the particular key.

For example:-

I have this firebase Database Structure:

```
user 

-> userid
          -> username 
          -> userPhone
          -> userAddress
                        -> [0]: City
                        -> [0]: State
```

Code:-

```
func listenUserIds() -> ListenerRegistration {
    let listener = db.collection("user")
        .whereField("userid", isEqualTo: self.profileID)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("listener error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                    let userAddress =  diff.document.data()
                    print(userAddress)
                }
            }
        }
    return listener
}
```

**ScreenShot:-**

[image: ScreenShot]

But when any user change their City, state the listener not call.

Can someone please explain to me how to set listener on city or state, when any change in the city and state value the listener automatically called. I've tried to implement by above but no results yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit hard to map your data structure to the code right now. Can you edit your question and show the actual JSON from your database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i'm using the firestore Database.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. That case, can you post a screenshot of a document (including its path) in the Firebase console?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated Please test

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it possible in my case?

Comment: There is no `userid` field in your documents, so you can't filter on that with ` .whereField("userid", isEqualTo: self.profileID)`. If the `202130` is your profileID, then you're looking for `db.collection("user").doc(profileID)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen '202130' is my unique userid. But i have already set same condition but when user change the details means city, state the listener not called automatically

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry for late reply. i'm not able to chance to try your answer due to some personal reason, give me sometime i will check and update you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't work for the data you showed. Since `202130` is the document ID, you should listen to it with:

```
let listener = db.collection("user")
    .doc(self.profileID)
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
```

Queries are needed to match a value *inside* the document. When you're matching the document **ID** use `doc()`.